# I would like to resolve when recv function doesn't return 0 when tcpip is disconnected

Tags: tcp, recv

Is there a case that recv function doesn't return 0 when tcpip is disconnected physicially? There is no calling return 0. So, Tcpip is no closed. What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Recv returns 0 only if TCP connection is closed explicitly by remote side.

Another cases of disconnect:

- If TCP connection is explicitly broken (TCP RST or ICMP unreachable packet received) then you can get error when read from the socket.
- If transit network goes down or remote host disappears then:

  - if timeout explicitly specified then read waits and return timeout error
  - if timeout is not specified then read waits maximum timeout (depends on system for Linux it is about 2 hours)

In last case you may:

- Try to enable keepalive requests on socket (SO_KEEPALIVE socket options)
- Do keepalive by yourself on application layer:

  - Send something to the peer and expect answer from it
  - If nothing received within timeout - close connection